# CNTK C# - Connect output to specific layer input

Tags: c#, neural-network, deep-learning, cntk

I need to create **10 neurons** each with **2 inputs**. Each of these has an output that should be connected to a layer that has **10 inputs** and an output.

My definition of input neurons:

```
Function in1 =  Util.Dense(CNTK.Variable.InputVariable(CNTK.NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 2 }), CNTK.DataType.Float), 1, computeDevice);
Function in2 =  Util.Dense(CNTK.Variable.InputVariable(CNTK.NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 2 }), CNTK.DataType.Float), 1, computeDevice);
Function in3 =  Util.Dense(CNTK.Variable.InputVariable(CNTK.NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 2 }), CNTK.DataType.Float), 1, computeDevice);
Function in4 =  Util.Dense(CNTK.Variable.InputVariable(CNTK.NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 2 }), CNTK.DataType.Float), 1, computeDevice);
Function in5 =  Util.Dense(CNTK.Variable.InputVariable(CNTK.NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 2 }), CNTK.DataType.Float), 1, computeDevice);
Function in6 =  Util.Dense(CNTK.Variable.InputVariable(CNTK.NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 2 }), CNTK.DataType.Float), 1, computeDevice);
Function in7 =  Util.Dense(CNTK.Variable.InputVariable(CNTK.NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 2 }), CNTK.DataType.Float), 1, computeDevice);
Function in8 =  Util.Dense(CNTK.Variable.InputVariable(CNTK.NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 2 }), CNTK.DataType.Float), 1, computeDevice);
Function in9 =  Util.Dense(CNTK.Variable.InputVariable(CNTK.NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 2 }), CNTK.DataType.Float), 1, computeDevice);
Function in10 = Util.Dense(CNTK.Variable.InputVariable(CNTK.NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 2 }), CNTK.DataType.Float), 1, computeDevice);
```

The layer with 10 inputs:

```
mergeLayer = Util.Dense(CNTK.NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 10 }), CNTK.DataType.Float, 1, computeDevice);
```

**How can I connect the 10 outputs to each input of mergeLayer?**

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do not create layer functions separetly, but pass one function as an input parameter to another. Concatenate data with cntk.splice . In Python:

```
import cntk as C

input1 = C.ops.input_variable((4, 2), np.float32)

in1 =  C.layers.Dense(1)( input1[0] )
in2 =  C.layers.Dense(1)( input1[1] )
in3 =  C.layers.Dense(1)( input1[2] )
in4 =  C.layers.Dense(1)( input1[3] )

allIn = C.splice( in1, in2, in3, in4, axis=0 )

mergeLayer = C.layers.Dense(1)( allIn )
```